# Change resolution from command line in virtual box

Tags: command-line, virtualbox, virtual-machine, resolution

In virtual box, how can I change the screen resolution from the command line? (Or if there's one for any type of computer, that might work too).

Comment: Do you want to do this from the host or guest command line?

Comment: maybe its me, but whats the OS?

Comment: A thorough answer can be found here on SO:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10725867/forcing-monitor-resolution-in-virtualbox-vm-on-linux-guest/10726041#10726041

Answer (score 23):

You can quickly "hint" the window to a specific size with the following command:

```
VBoxManage controlvm <uuid>|<name> setvideomodehint <xres> <yres> <bpp>
```

For example, if you have a guest called "Windows XP Pro", and you wish to set the resolution to 1024x600 at 32 bits per pixel (aka 32 bit) you would use the following command:

```
VBoxManage controlvm "Windows XP Pro" setvideomodehint 1024 600 32
```

There are some prerequisites for this however:

1. This only works if you've launched the Guest OS from a windowed environment on the Host OS (ie. Windows / X Windows / Mac OS Desktop).
2. Guest Additions must be installed in the Guest OS.

Comment: VirtualBox OSE 4.0.4 doesn't let you change the resolution to larger than normal display size with that.

Comment: Also note that that command must be run while the VM is running. My experience also indicates that it is necessary to set `VBoxManage setextradata global GUI/MaxGuestResolution any` (before starting the VM). The auto resize should also be disabled in the view menu. If the intended resolution is particularly high (especially if it's higher than the host resolution), more video memory may have to be assigned.

Comment: Is it possible to persist this setting somehow?

Answer (score 5):

First, the vm must be turned on, you can power on with command:

```
# VBoxManage startvm "VPN" --type headless
```

Before you can change the resolution:

```
# VBoxManage controlvm "VPN" setvideomodehint 1024 768 24
```

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to change it from within the guest:

**In Windows**: there are a couple tools that allow you to do this easily from the command line, notably [Display Changer](http://www.12noon.com/displaychanger.htm).

**In Linux**: Use `xrandr -q` to list available display modes, then `xrandr -s #` where `#` is the number of the display mode you wish to use. `xrandr -q` will display these number options next to each display option.

Comment: the 10k x 8k resolution i tried to set with display changer did have no effect on virtualbox ose 4.0.4

Answer (score 1):

$ VBoxManage setextradata "WinXP" "CustomVideoMode1" "1440x900x16"

 Where "WinXP" is your virtual machine name. This solution is somewhat close to truth :)

Comment: does not work here on VirtualBox OSE 4.0.4

Answer (score 0):

Look inside the documentation provided with VirtualBox. The [VBoxManage program](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html#vboxmanage) gives you the ability to modify VMs from the command line. You can't do this while the machine is running, however. To do that you'll need to find a way to script the resolution change for the operating system you are virtualizing.

Comment: please note that in some cases you will have to install "guest additions" in order to properly use VBoxManage, see may question regarding a similar issue: http://superuser.com/questions/30924/resolution-issues-running-ubuntu-on-virtualbox

Answer (score 0):

The MS Windows RDP client for Mac OSX has a preference setting that I had to adjust in addition to adding the custom video modes (shown above).

Select Preferences from the RDC menu, then click on 'Display'.
(I was going to post a screen image, but the spam prevention feature prevented it.)

By selecting 'Full screen', I was able to get the display mode changed to the full screen of the client computer. In this case, a MacBook with a screen resolution of 1280x800.

Comment: Upload the image/link without embedding it and  someone will fix it. Also "Shown above" dosen't really cut it since the order of answers changes on SU - you may want to explicitly reference which answer you're referring to in future