# Ubuntu resolution on Virtual Box(Mac OSX)

Tags: macos, ubuntu, virtualbox, resolution, display

I'm running Ubuntu 9.1 inside VirtualBox 3.1.6 on Mac OS X 10.6.3. The screen resolution won't go beyond 800x600 and Ubuntu can't detect my monitor type.

How can I increase the resolution beyond 800x600? Are there any drivers I can install, for example?

Comment: Also see <http://superuser.com/questions/30924/resolution-issues-running-ubuntu-on-virtualbox>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu won't be able to detect **your** monitor type because the Virtual Machine doesn't see your monitor, it sees a virtual monitor. If you have the Virtual Machine Additions installed then you should be able to change your resolutions or enter seamless mode for a more usable experience.

Comment: You should install the plugin using root login in ubuntu. Once the system is restarted after installation you will see mouse integration and ability to change screen resolution.

Comment: I just discovered this, this morning :-).  Thank you so much for your help!